# Removing values from edges

Tags: java

I have data in following format

```
String [] data = new String[]{"-166444026   0   file    20130801",
"-166444026 0   file    20130802",
"-166444027 0   file    20130802"};
```

These are tab seperated strings.
Now.. 
So we have
key, value,type,date.

What I want is to keep latest unique keys in the list.
So for example...
The output of this operation should be...

```
["-166444026    0   file    20130802",
"-166444027 0   file    20130802"];
```

Because -166444026 is present twice but the one i removed has date of 20130801 and this one has a later date?

I wrote the code.. but this just returns everything.(I thought it was suppose to remove.. but it isnt..)??

Any clues?

```
package org.random_scripts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Regex {
    private static boolean alreadyExists(Map<String, Long> dict, String key) {
        if(dict.containsKey(key))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    private static void removeEdge(ArrayList<JSONObject>edgeList, String key) {

        for(JSONObject edge:edgeList) {
            if (edge.get("destination").equals(key))
                edge.remove(key);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] data = new String[]{"-166444026   0   file    20130801",
                                    "-166444026 0   file    20130802",
                                    "-166444026 0   file    20130802"};

        try {
            String key = "185479485";
            JSONObject jsn = new JSONObject();
            jsn.put("source", key.toString());

            ArrayList<JSONObject> edges = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
            Map<String, Long> tracker = new HashMap<String, Long>();
            for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                String value = data[i];
                //edgeString+= value.toString()+",";
                String[] typeChunks = value.toString().split("\t");

                String destination = typeChunks[0];
                Double reputation = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(typeChunks[1]));
                System.out.println(tracker.values().toString());
                JSONObject edgeJson = new JSONObject();
                Long date = Long.valueOf(typeChunks[3]);
                if(alreadyExists(tracker,destination)) {
                    Long prev_date = tracker.get(destination);
                    System.out.println(true);
                    if (date > prev_date) {
                        //remove edge
                        removeEdge(edges,destination);
                        System.out.println("edges are" + edges.toString());

                    }
                }
                else {
                    tracker.put(destination, date);

                }


                edgeJson.put("destination", destination);
                edgeJson.put("reputation", reputation);
                edgeJson.put("type", typeChunks[2]);
                edges.add(edgeJson);

            }
            jsn.put("edgelist", edges);
            System.out.println(jsn.toJSONString());
            //context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(jsn.toJSONString()));
            //edgeString = edgeString.substring(0,edgeString.length()-1);
            //edgeString+="]";
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exceptiom");
                //context.write(NullWritable.get(),new Text(s) );
            }




        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), then assign each line to a key in the `HashMap`.

The `HashMap` will retain only the latest assigned value, so you can decide if you want to reassign it or not depending on its date.

If you need to preserve the original order of the lines, you can use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which preserves insertion order.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Search a last word with a regexp and then just iterate the array?

```
    String key = data[data.length - 1].replaceAll(".*\\s", "");
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].endsWith(key)) {
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
    }
```

Out:

```
-166444026 0   file    20130802
-166444027 0   file    20130802
```